# ParameterMissing when a parameter is empty in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

In my API I have an endpoint at /api/orders

When doing a POST call with the following JSON:

```
{"order":{}}
```

I get a ActionController::ParameterMissing: param not found: order

My strong parameters function looks like this:

```
def order_params
  params.require('order')
end
```

Why is not letting me pass an empty 'order', if I do:

```
{"order":{"test":"value"}}
```

It works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because this is how `.require` works. See the API: http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-require

Rails isn't ensuring that the key exists but, rather, that there are parameters `.present?` for this key.

The source for `.require` helps elucidate this:

```
# File actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb, line 182
def require(key)
  self[key].presence || raise(ParameterMissing.new(key))
end
```

And `{}.present? # => false`.